# ttf_lookup_cache attribute not found in FontManager when using plot()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I try the following (in python 3):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
>>> pl.plot([1, 2, 3])
>>> pl.show()
```

I get an error with at the end:

```
AttributeError: 'FontManager' object has no attribute 'ttf_lookup_cache'
```

But when I do the following it works:

```
>>> from matplotlib.font_manager import FontManager
>>> FontManager().ttf_lookup_cache
{}
```

But the `FontManager` constructor takes some time (~1.5s), while the first code does not.

Also, the above code works perfectly fine with python 2, and I found some posts asking similar questions like:

- [Plotting with Matplotlib in Python 3 pylab: Tkinter and Qt FontManager errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578129/plotting-with-matplotlib-in-python-3-pylab-tkinter-and-qt-fontmanager-errors)
- [Matplotlib font_manager.py font finding error](https://superuser.com/questions/476082/matplotlib-font-manager-py-font-finding-error)

...but none of the answers worked for me.

If it helps, I am working on Ubuntu 14.04.4 with python 3.4.3 and `matplotlib` 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a big of digging, I realized the problem was probably the old version of `matplotlib` I was using (installed using `apt-get install`). I tried removing it and installing it using `pip` and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-matplotlib
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

After that, I got a warning the first time I imported `matplotlib.pyplot` (about building font cache). Now everything works fine.

The installed version of `matplotlib` using `pip3` is **1.5.1** (from **1.3.1** using `apt`).